# Website navbar list displaying vertically despite li's inline css setting

Tags: css

I'm having an issue with the css on a practice website. I'm testing out a website and my navbar "ul" list is set to inline yet my list is still coming across vertically instead of horizontally. Do you guys have any ideas what I might be missing?

```
#navbar {
    float: left;
    z-index: 2;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: -100px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-254px;
    background-color: brown;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 8000px;
}
#navbar ul{
    z-index: 2;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: fixed;
    margin: -10px;
}
#navbar li {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;}
```

This is embarrassing, but I'm making a D&D site for practice. Here is a screenshot:
[The ill-fated website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKXCe.png)

I see the answer mentioned for adding flex and will try it and get back to you on my success.

Comment: What is your work till here? Can you provide code blocks? I think you should ask this question three hours later ;)

Comment: touché. Still nervous about submitting with my lowly programming knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

if you add `display: flex;` to the CSS of your `ul`, you make it a flexbox container - the default settings will display the list items of your navbar horizontally.

addition/edit: If you want to do it without flexbox: don't put the `display:inline` on the `ul`, but on the `li` elements, and better make it `inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

```
    #navbar {
float: left;
z-index: 2;
position: fixed;
margin-top: -100px;
left:50%;
margin-left:-254px;
background-color: brown;
height: 200px;
width: 300px;
border-radius: 8000px;
```

}

```
#navbar ul{
z-index: 2;
list-style-type: none;
position: fixed;
margin: -10px;
//Add this
display: inline-block;
```

}

```
#navbar li {
//Remove
display: inline; //<---- Remove this
text-align: center;
margin-right: 15px;
padding-left: 100px;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;}
```